# How can I fix go get: disabled by -mod=vendor

Tags: go, go-modules

I used `export GO111MODULE=on`

when i type `go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag`

I got **`go get: disabled by -mod=vendor`**

so i can't use the go get any more, anyone who can help me?

and my `go env` like this:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/maple/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=" -mod=vendor"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/maple/go"
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/b0/gjtsl1sn61977y7xldkg5f540000gn/T/go-build663727012=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

i found there has a `GOFLAGS=" -mod=vendor"`, how can i change it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked.. What did you try? Any research?

Comment: `GOFLAGS= go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag`

Answer (score 8):

Based on my personal setup, until this gets fixed/cleaned up upstream, you can simply unset this flag in your variable, i.e:

```
$ export GOFLAGS=""
```

This because you don't have any other flags but -mod currently set.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Golang documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#build-commands), this setting tells `go` to not automatically update `go.mod` if an imported module is not found. To disable the read-only mode, you can run

```
go env -w GOFLAGS=''
```